# Counting the number of occurences or higher value in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I was wondering if there was a way to use AWK or SED to find certain values that are higher than the argument you gave to the script inside a file. This being

```
./script.sh CITY VALUE
```

The value, in this case, is the $2 or second argument which is going to the basis of our search, so if we have a file,

**dummy2.txt**

Format: Name;ID;Profession;email;rating;number of visits;balance

```
John Trevolta;12334;dentist;gmail;0;0;431
Isabella;4567;dentist;gmail;0;0;400
```

and if we input,

```
./script.sh CITY 400
```

It should be able to read every column ( the seventh in this case ($7)) from this exact dummy2.txt and output the number of times it finds a value higher than the one we gave it so the desired output would be:

```
1
```

But the current Output I'm given is the following:

```
1 John Trevolta;12334;dentist;gmail;0;0;431
```

So with this, this is my current code that  I have for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Please insert arguments"
        exit 1
elif [ "$#" -lt 2 ] || [ -z "$1"  ]
    then
        echo "Error 404: No arguments found"
        exit 1
else
    grep -c "$1" dummy.txt
    awk -v  x=$2 '$7>x{ i++ }END{ print "Found:" i }' dummy2.txt
    fi
```

I have already added some suggestions found in the comments but unfortunately, it only prints,

```
Found:
```

It doesn't start counting the i or even say it's value. I don't know if I need to initialize it or not and if I need to put ''/""/$ on it for it to be read.

Comment: `"$7 -gt $Arg2"` isn't a valid awk expression...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! What do you think I should put in there tho?

Comment: Something like `awk -F; '$7>x' x="$var1" dummy2.txt ...`

Comment: Edit: nevermind, I was missing a ". tho is it possible to instead of giving me the whole line, to just count how many? Instead of printing the whole line, say 2 if it found 2 greater than the agr

Comment: oh and if you could explain to me in greater detail the way you used and why it gets recognized while mine doesn't. I'd appreciate it! I'm new to shell and I'm still learning it's quirks

Comment: Calling `awk` from a shell script is rarely necessary. If you are using `awk` -- it can generally handle the entire program.

Comment: `if [awk -F';' "$7 -gt $Arg2"]` contains so many false assumptions and errors it's mind-boggling. The argument to `[` should be a single string and it will check whether that string is empty; you absolutely need a space between `[` and its argument; but obviously the string `awk` etc is not empty. `if awk -F';' -v value="$Arg2" '$7 <= value { exit 1 } END { exit 0 }'` makes sense syntactically, but it's not clear which file Awk should read as its standard input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: Being honest here, that if statement was written when I made the post, so I really didn't pay attention to the rules ( I know I probably should have ) but it was meant as an illustration of what I was thinking on doing in the if statement. hence me asking how to use it in an if statement. Do apologize for all the sore eyes after reading that bit of code!

Answer (score 1):

Because of (the lack of ) input, assume the following input (numbers.txt):

```
een 1
twee 2
drie 3
vier 4
vijf 5
zes 6
zeven 7
```

Then:

`awk -v arg1=2 '$2>arg1{ i++ }END{ print "Found " i " lines greater than " arg1 }' numbers.txt`

will print: `Found 5 lines greater than 2`

and:

`awk -v arg1=5 '$2>arg1{ i++ }END{ print "Found " i " lines greater than " arg1 }' numbers.txt`

will print: `Found 2 lines greater than 5`

EDIT: (because....)

When creating a script like this (lets name it `test.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

rm numbers.txt
echo een 1 >>numbers.txt
echo twee 2 >>numbers.txt
echo drie 3 >>numbers.txt
echo vier 4 >>numbers.txt
echo vijf 5 >>numbers.txt
echo zes 6 >>numbers.txt
echo zeven 7 >>numbers.txt
echo acht 8 >>numbers.txt

awk -v arg1=3 '$2>arg1{ i++ }END{ print "Found " i " lines greater than " arg1 }' numbers.txt

awk -v arg1=5 '$2>arg1{ i++ }END{ print "Found " i " lines greater than " arg1 }' numbers.txt

awk -v arg1=$1 '$2>arg1{ i++ }END{ print "Found " i " lines greater than " arg1 }' numbers.txt
```

The output will be:

```
$ ./test.sh 7
Found 5 lines greater than 3
Found 3 lines greater than 5
Found 1 lines greater than 7
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it prints a blank line for some reason

Comment: Than you did not copy/paste it exactly?

Comment: I changed it a tiny bit.
 awk -v  x="$2" '$7>=x {$i++ }END{print "Found:" '$i'}' dummy2.txt 
It prints the found but not the I, regardless if I put $ or not

Comment: Where did you read that you need single quotes around `$i` ?

Comment: Just put them to see if it would make any difference but it didn't

Comment: I think the i isn't starting because it can read the x var

Comment: I added an example script with parameter to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223552/discussion-between-box-and-luuk).